# D3 x axis not showing all data

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to perform a visualisation using D3's bar chart graph. Unfortunately, I am having some trouble to get it running as I expect.

Here's a link to what I am seeing: 
[Block Example](https://bl.ocks.org/blasrodri/a66e64d9a3113755b0fddcb16c444537)

1. I would like to get a range of data from 2012 until the end of 2017 in the x-axis (even if the data point is zero).
2. Have a label for each tick. Currently, the x axis has labels only for a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, you are overriding the previously set domain for the x scale, which is the one you want (going from 2012 to 2018).

Thus, simply remove this line:

```
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return timeFormatter(d.Date); }));
```

Here is your updated bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/be8f59fa47b9ca274934e377ac3d899a